# Запрос @Query из JPA репозитория возвращает пустой список

Tags: java, spring, запрос, jpa

При создании динамического запроса в БД, который потом тестируется на методах, возвращается пустой список.

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface PlayerRepositoryImpl extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {

    @Query("select pl from Player pl where " +
            "(:name is null or pl.name like concat('%',:name,'%')) and " +
            "(:title is null or pl.title like concat('%',:title,'%')) and " +
            "(:race is null or pl.race = :race) and " +
            "(:profession is null or pl.profession = :profession) and " +
            "(:after is null or pl.birthday >= :after) and " +
            "(:before is null or pl.birthday <= :before) and " +
            "(:banned is null or pl.banned = :banned) and " +
            "(:minExperience is null or pl.experience >= :minExperience) and " +
            "(:maxExperience is null or pl.experience <= :maxExperience) and " +
            "(:minLevel is null or pl.level >= :minLevel) and " +
            "(:maxLevel is null or pl.level <= :maxLevel)")
    List<Player> findAllByParams (
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("title") String title,
            @Param("race") Race race,
            @Param("profession") Profession profession,
            @Param("after") Date after, @Param("before") Date Before,
            @Param("banned") Boolean banned,
            @Param("minExperience") Integer minExperience, @Param("maxExperience") Integer 
            maxExperience,
            @Param("minLevel") Integer minLevel, @Param("maxLevel") Integer maxLevel,
            Pageable pageable);
}
```

метод для теста

//test1

```java
@Test
public void getAllWithoutFiltersReturnAllPlayers() throws Exception {

    ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/players"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    MvcResult result = resultActions.andReturn();
    String contentAsString = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

    List<PlayerInfoTest> actual = mapper.readValue(contentAsString, typeReference);
    List<PlayerInfoTest> expected = testsHelper.getPlayerInfosByPage(0, 3,
            testsHelper.getAllPlayers());
    assertEquals("Возвращается не правильный результат при запросе GET /rest/players.", expected, actual);
}
```

Если заменить данный запрос на простейший

```java
@Query("select pl from Player pl")
```

то тест проходит и возвращается список игроков.
Но стоит добавить дополнительные параметры и тест падает.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Возвращается не правильный результат при запросе GET /rest/players. 

Expected :[PlayerInfoTest{id=1, name='Ниус', birthday=2010-10-12}, PlayerInfoTest{id=2, name='Никрашш', birthday=2010-02-14}, PlayerInfoTest{id=3, name='Эззэссэль', birthday=2006-02-28}]

Actual   :[]
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at com.game.controller.GetAllTest.getAllWithoutFiltersReturnAllPlayers(GetAllTest.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Скажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: видимо проблема в том, что не находятся игроки удовлетворяющие вашему запросу

Comment: Ну а  почему тогда валится даже тест без всяких фильтров после добавления хотя бы одного нового параметра, я с name пробовал.
Например возьмем два теста
getAllWithoutFiltersReturnAllPlayers()
и
getAllWithFiltersNamePageNumber()
Если делать простейший запрос на всех игроков без фильтров, то первый тест проходит, второй соответственно нет, так как там уже по параметру name нужен запрос.
Но стоит мне добавить запрос на поиск по name "(:name is null or pl.name like concat('%',:name,'%')) and " начинает возвращать пустой список и первый тест, хотя мне кажется он должен корректно отрабатывать.

Comment: А почему вы параметр проверяете на null, а не pl.name к примеру?

Comment: Чтобы получить отфильтрованный список, например только по параметру tittle игрока. То есть, сделать такую выборку на сайте, в которой не будет участвовать name игрока, или какие-то еще параметры.

Comment: @Евгений я намекнул вам на ответ. Ошибка именно там))